# With an array parameter, how to give element [1] and [2] a default value? While while allowing the user to specify Element [0]?

Tags: powershell

With an array parameter, how to give element `[1]` and `[2]` a default value? While while allowing the user to specify Element `[0]`?

```
Function test{
param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$True,Position=0)]
        [ValidateRange(0, 360)]
        [Array]$Color = ($Color, 100, 100)
)       [String]$Path = $PWD
$Color
}
```

The output of `Test -Color 150` should be:

```
150
100
100
```

Yet This should also be possible, `Test -Color 150, 70, 80`:

```
150
70
80
```

Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no such parameter syntax feature, you'll have to modify the parameter variable manually after parameter binding takes place:

```
function test {
  param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true, Position=0, ValueFromRemainingArguments=$true)]
    [ValidateRange(0, 360)]
    [ValidateCount(1, 3)]
    [Array]$Color = @()
  )

  if ($Color.Count -lt 3) {
    $Color = @($Color; ,100 * (3 - $Color.Count))
  }

  "Colors: $Color"
}
```

Now you can do:

```
PS ~> test 123
Colors: 123 100 100
PS ~> test 123 360
Colors: 123 360 100
PS ~> test 123 360 180
Colors: 123 360 180
```